# Convert bot template code to deploy on service fabric

Tags: botframework, azure-service-fabric

I have developed a bot project which I need to deploy in service fabric. I have a sample project in service fabric which works and I have called my Messages Controller (in bot project) from within an endpoint on the service fabric project.

I am able to receive requests through that endpoint but I am getting null reference errors inside the code and no requests are successful.

Can Bot framework be run in Service Fabric?

Comment: does the bot work on the emulator or anywhere else?

Comment: @JasonSowers Yes, I have it successfully working it on Skype, Slack and Teams. I need to modify it for Service Fabric.